# Parse JSON data from URL via jQUERY to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing

I have this file wiht JSON data:
https://suggest.autocompleteapi.com/ap7d7hg5jezr/drg121016?prefix=pe&size=10

and I want very simple script in jQUERY to parse this data,
via jQUERY to HTML webpage to ul style like this:

```
<ul>
<li>K704 Alkoholové zlyhávanie pečene</li>
<li>K741 Skleróza pečene</li>
........
.......
</ul>
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, script : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp, I change URL but dont work

Comment: @Peter The script there is for appending plain text to to a `DIV`. Did you change it to add `<li>` element to your `<ul>`? Show your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say research everything prior to seeking help on SO. This does what you want by pulling the data via Ajax using `.getJSON`

```js
$.getJSON("https://suggest.autocompleteapi.com/ap7d7hg5jezr/drg121016?prefix=pe&size=10", function(result) {

  var data = result.suggestions;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.lists').append('<li>' + data[i].value + '</li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="lists">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanx, it works, you save me a lot of time, I am new in jQUERY

Comment: @Peter What's the difference between this and what you originally tried? Except for using a `for` loop instead of `$.each`, it seems identical to the w3schools page you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
//if the data is one string from ajax response, 
//you have to parse the string to json object first
//let yourData = JSON.parse(ajax_response);

let yourData = {'suggestion':[
                              {'value':'K704 Alkoholové zlyhávanie pečene'},
                              {'value':'K718 Toxická choroba pečene s inými poruchami pečene'},
                              {'value':'K718 Toxická choroba pečene s inými poruchami pečene'}
                             ]
               }

let ulPlacedAt = $('body'); //you can change it to other object you like
let ulBody = '';
yourData['suggestion'].forEach(function(item) {
    ulBody += '<li>'+item['value'] + '</li>';
  }
)
ulBody = '<ul>' + ulBody + '</ul>';
ulPlacedAt.append(ulBody);
```

Comment: Thanx it works, but I have esternal URL file with JSON: https://suggest.autocompleteapi.com/ap7d7hg5jezr/drg121016?prefix=pe&size=10, put this file in "let yourData"?

Comment: try this: $.ajax({
                url: 'your_url',
                type: 'POST',
                data: post_params,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    var yourData = JSON.parse(result);}